# Decimal separator replace on DataGridView Cell update

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` where the user updates some quantities and prices in the database. The problem is that sometimes the user might use `"."` instead of `","` for the decimal separator, and this messes the data in the database (for instance, when the user types `"2.7"`, after he leaves the `cell` the value left is `"27"`). So far I have tried using the `CellValidating` and `CellValueChanged` events but I couldn't solve my problem. (code below, first from `CellValidating`, second from `CellValueChanged`)

```
'CellValidating
If e.FormattedValue.ToString().Contains(".") Then
     DataGridViewSample(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString().Replace(".", ",")
End If

'CellValueChanged
If DataGridViewSample(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString().Contains(".") Then
     DataGridViewSample(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString().Replace(".", ",")
End If
```

I am sorry if my request seems dumb, but I am asked to prevent this kind of user "error". I would like to programatically replace the `"."` with `","` or to make the update in such a way that `"."` would be considered as `","` by the compiler (other ways of solving this are also accepted). Any piece of advice would be great, have a nice day!

Comment: Do you want to insert `Decimal Point` after updating `DatagridView`? Is that what you want?

Comment: Not really. The user will insert decimal values most of the times, since quantities and prices are rarely integers. The problem is some users mistake "." for "," (which I know is not the same thing), and they use "." when typing the values in the grid, which is not good. I want that each time a user inserts "." instead of ",", the "." separator would be replaced with /considered as ",".

Comment: What event are you using to save the data in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this solve don't use the formats.

You need to use the textbox object from the cell:

```
'This will represent the content of the cell
Dim editBox As TextBox = Nothing
```

In the `EditingControlShowing` event from your datagridview you need to get the `textbox` object and adding a `keyDown` event:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As 
DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles 
DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    'Put the column index of the cell
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 Then
        If TryCast(e.Control, TextBox) IsNot Nothing Then
            editBox = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)

            'Removing and then adding the keyDown event in the cell
            RemoveHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf Cell_KeyDown
            AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf Cell_KeyDown
        End If

    End If
End Sub


Private Sub Cell_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)
    'To commit the changes of the cell
    DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
End Sub
```

Then, in the `cellLeave` event commit the changes of the cell again, replace the `"."` with `","` and set the value to the `textbox`:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) 
Handles DataGridView1.CellLeave
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 2 And DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
        DataGridView1.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit)
        DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString.Replace(".", ",")
        editBox.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Finally, in the `CellEndEdit` put the code to save the data in your database.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    'Code to save in database here...
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Will give it a try as soon as possible and will come back with a reply, thank you very much!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, altough I followed your steps carefully :(

Comment: This is the example: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0bguxkxfgp0v4bb/ReplacingDecimal.rar?dl=0 give it a try. Good luck.

Comment: It works in the example you provided, but as soon as I integrate the code in my application it does not work. I guess there is an event or something like that that modifies the way the string is formatted (if it helps, the data from my DataGridView is saved in a SQL DataBase). I will look through my code and as soon as I find what's wrong I will mark you answer as accepted and eventually upvote it (if my reputation allows me). Sorry for making you waste your time with making a new solution and uploading it for my mistake... :)